# Dynamically create views and map them to objects

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview

I created the following activity:

[image]

it does scroll, and if you scroll you see this

[image]

So you have two rooms: the first is a double, and has two passengers (paxes). The second room is a single one, with just one passenger.

Now, my activity needs to be dynamically created in order to adapt to the room combination the user has chosen to book. It could be two single rooms, two doubles and so on...

What I need to do in this activity is to let the user insert the name and surname of each passenger and retrieve them so I can send them to the webservice in order to complete the reservation.

I already have an object for passengers. It's the class Pax and has three fields:

- `String title`
- `String name`
- `String surname`

you can guess what it's for.

Now, I also created some RoomInstance objects, and each RoomInstance has the following parameters:

- `String type` --> for single, double
- `int numberOfPaxes` --> how many people in this room
- `ArrayList<Pax> paxes` --> the list of passengers

I created the activities above by cycling on a list of RoomInstances I create at search-time. This is what I do:

```
        for(LatestSearchData.RoomInstance ri : latestSearchData.getRooms()) {
        /**
         * Sets up a header for each room in our list
         */
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PaxSelectorActivity.this);
        View inflatedHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pax_selector_header, null, false);
        TextView headerText = (TextView) inflatedHeader.findViewById(R.id.pax_selector_header);
        headerText.setText(ri.getType());
        hostingLayout.addView(inflatedHeader);

        for(int i = 0; i < ri.getNumberOfPaxes(); i++) {
            /**
             * Sets up a layout to fill up for each pax
             */
            View inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pax_selector_single_room, null, false);
            EditText nameEditText = (EditText) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText surnnameEditText = (EditText) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.surname);
            (...)
            hostingLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

I inflate a header (the ones with written DOUBLE and SINGLE in the screenshot) for each room and then a activity_pax_selector_single_room row for each passenger. It works gracefully and I get the exact activity I want. But... how can I map the data inserted with my rooms and passengers? I'd like to link them in order to be able to retrieve them easily as soon as the user taps on "Next" and put the right passenger in the right room, since this is a valuable information.

I was thinking about extending LinearLayout and create a custom view with a RoomInstance parameter, then passing the RoomInstance to the layout. But this seems to me to be a huge MVC-logic break and I'd rather not to. Also, since the list of rooms won't ever be too long and I'm going to have an arbitrary number of headers between passengers, I thought it wouldn't be a clever idea to use a RecyclerView... or is it?

Comment: i do belive de only way to keep reference of the EditText of each room is by creating a CustomView that extends LinearLayout or Relative and make an instance to each room then add it to the layout in running time.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Akariuz, that's what I thought as well, but I was wondering if there's some kind of Adapter which could act as a link between the layout and the object it describes...